# Find cells less than todays date VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a form which will find any cell with a date value less than todays date within a single column and return the row number. I am trying to use the Match function but only receive errors.

Anybody have any idea where to start with this?

Cheers

James

Comment: You are being far to vague.  What have you tried.

Comment: Apologies, this is my first time posting on here. I want to be able to find the deatails of an entry to a table with a date before today. I've been trying to go along the lines of: Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(<Date, Sheets("Lab Stock").Range("I:I"), 0)

This is probably the completely wrong way to go about it. I only get errors returned. I just want to return a row number as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Yes this can be done differently by using VBA, but if you don't know VBA it will be hard.  You might be able to use excel formulas like this and this may give you what you need.

If you dates are in column A and start in A1.

Add this formula to B2 and copy it down into the other cells in the column.

```
=IF(A1<TODAY(),ROW(A1),"After")
```

This is a starting point.

I don't know what you are using the form for.  eg what if many dates are before today, do you just take the first one?

ie
Add this to C1

```
=IF(B1<>"After",1,0)
```

Add this to C2 and copy down

```
=IF(B2<>"After",C1+1,C1)
```

Add this to D1

```
=IF(C1<>0,A1,"")
```

Add this to D2 and copy down

```
=IF(AND(C2<>0,C1=0),A2,"")
```

Add this to cell E1

```
 =SUM(D:D)
```

Chnage column D and E to have date format.

Cell E1 now gives you the first date in the list less than today.

Harvey